# Matlab: Intersect solutions

Tags: matlab, intersection

I need to build a script in which i have to calculate the intersect solutions for some equations.

For example:

18 - Kp > 0
6Kp + 72 > 0

In matlab code:

syms kp
solve('18-kp>0')

ans =

Dom::Interval(-Inf, 18)

solve('6*kp+72>0')

ans =

Dom::Interval(-12, Inf)

I know that the intersect of the solution is (-12, 18) but how do i write in Matlab?
Can i take the boundary of the intervals? For example:
max (-inf,-12) = -12
min (18, inf) = 18
so the intersection will be (-12, 18)
 I'm not running a MUPAD Interface! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single solve to get an Interval that satisfies both inequalities -

Running

```
solve('6*kp+72>0, 18-kp>0')
```

will give an answer of Dom::Interval(-12, 18)